# Trouble making responsive email template

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-email

I'm working on a responsive email design and running into some trouble. It partially works but I'm thinking I need fresh set of eyes and help cause I'm not finding the solutions. I think the nav links are what's creating most of the problems but unsure if that's really the problem.

Basically I want the email to be responsive and stack to pretty much a single column with exceptions.

The problems I'm running into are these:

Whole page isn't fully responsive - ( get sidescroll part of the way )

wide ads 565x70 doesn't seem to change size

Top nav with social icons are not stacking properly. I want the left links to not move (maybe center if needed for small screens) but social icons stack below the other links. 3 columns wide preferably just like they are now just want the icons below the menu.

nav menu below the logo - Here I want them to center with smaller screens but also stack in order with 2 columns wide. I've tried fluid text that wraps but it didn't seem to work for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tested and tried other resource items but seem to be failing with what should work according to the other resources.

Below is the link to template.

http://bit.ly/1u67HDG

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need a responsive css. I am a big fan of Twitter Bootstrap. You will design your entire email as a normal site with your  tags and include your CSS.

Here you can look at these awesome CSS's that are responsive:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/
http://metroui.org.ua/
http://www.99lime.com/
http://purecss.io/
http://gumbyframework.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting inline widths on images and tables. The CSS in the header can't override the inline declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It seems that I mostly had each table on their own. So I created wrappers, double checked the widths re-added classes and etc. It seems to be working pretty good now.

Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes helps. Thanks again.

P.S. J.otero - Frameworks are good if you're using it for the web but they will do little to nothing for email.